# Pantheon Files Side Panel CSS

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon, gtk

How can I change the color of the Pantheon files sidebar from dark to light? I can't seem to find the CSS that controls this aspect of it. If anyone knows where to find it please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code file `src/View/Sidebar.vala` (cf. `apt-get source pantheon-files`) it seems that the `sidebar` and `source-list` classes are applied to the sidebar.

In `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/` you have "source-list" classes defined in the files `granite-widgets.css`, `gtk-widgets.css` and `gtk-widgets-dark.css`. You should customize one or more of these.

Comment: I should have clarify that I was using Arc Theme. I did however find the place within the Arc theme to fix the issues.

Comment: Arc-OSX Line: 3654 for Marlin/Pantheon Files background
MarlinViewWindow .source-list.sidebar.view {
  background-color: rgba(245, 246, 247, 0.95); } /53, 57, 69, 0.95)/

Arc-OSX Line:  3660 for Marlin/Pantheon Files font color
MarlinViewWindow .source-list.sidebar.view row {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #3D414C; } /BAC3CF/
Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz2E21JweMDPcWNEcWNGdGQwWlU

Answer (score 1):

In file gtk.css, change this:

MarlinViewWindow .source-list.sidebar.view {
  background-color: white; }